# Activity SplashScreen is not declared in Android Manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest

I keep getting an error when trying to run my app that says.... The activity SplashScreen is not declared in AndroidManifest.xml

Any ideas as it's driving me mad! :-)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sjmplanningfinal">

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">

    <activity android:name="com.example.sjmplanningfinal.SplashScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.example.sjmplanningfinal.SJMPlanningHome" />
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Is it solved yet? If not I will post my answer to the question.

Comment: Sort of. I'm still getting the same error after removing the Main bit but now I need to work out how to add the application tag? Or where to add it or what to add?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sjmplanningfinal">
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">

    <activity android:name="com.example.sjmplanningfinal.SplashScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.example.sjmplanningfinal.SJMPlanningHome" />
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter> </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the tag `action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN`  from SJMPlanningHome. You have declared two activities as MAIN.

Comment: Doh. That was a basic stupid error on my part. What do you declare other pages as or do you just remove the whole line?

Comment: Remove the whole line. But you are also missing the <application> tag...

Answer (score 0):

Each android application should have defined "application" tag.. as a main tag in manifest.. and then inside application you define activities. Here is structure of manifest: you can check also here: [Manifest structure](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>
   <uses-permission />
   <permission />
   <permission-tree />
   <permission-group />
   <instrumentation />
   <uses-sdk />
   <uses-configuration />
   <uses-feature />
   <supports-screens />
   <compatible-screens />
   <supports-gl-texture />
   <application>
      <activity>
         <intent-filter>
            <action />
            <category />
            <data />
         </intent-filter>
         <meta-data />
      </activity>
   </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are missing the `application` tag. You have to put the tag before

```
android:allowBackup="true"
```

and after

```
<activity android:name="com.example.sjmplanningfinal.SJMPlanningHome">
```

Second, you forgot to close `activity` after filtering the intent for `SJMPlanningHome`.

This is the full code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sjmplanningfinal">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">

        <activity android:name="com.example.sjmplanningfinal.SplashScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.sjmplanningfinal.SJMPlanningHome">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```